# Excel - How to get expression text rather than the value

Tags: excel

I'm having problem with a big set of Excel data. One others had inputted the data like this:

```
A
10
10:12
11:12:15
```

My task is to convert it to something like this:

```
B
Pig
Pig:Koala
Dog:Koala:Bird
```

I was trying to use substitute:

```
= SUBSTITUTE(A1, "10", "Pig")
```

But the problem is, Excel recognizes those value in A column as other data types (number, time...) and the SUBSTITUTE doesn't work on those types.

How could I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Format the cells as `TEXT`, then paste your data. This way Excel will keep the the input as text, instead of autoconverting it to `DATE` or `NUMBER`. Then use `SUBSTITUTE`.

Comment: I think this might be very helpful to u http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/671-excel-change-number-to-text.html

Comment: I don't mind. Please share your code if you have any.

Comment: @HarryNinh .. you may use Sean Cheashire's answer to convert your value to string .. then use substitute function ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will return a string that matches what excel is displaying.

```
Option Explicit

Function ToText(r As Range) As String
If r.Count <> 1 Then
    ToText = "#ERR!"
    Exit Function
End If
ToText = IIf(r.NumberFormat = "General", CStr(r.Value), Format(r.Value, r.NumberFormat))
End Function
```

for example, if `10:11:12` is in A1, which excel thinks is a time, and is formatted this way, then `=ToText(A1)` will return the string `10:11:12`, which you can then manipulate as you would any other text

put this into a module on the spreadsheet ( <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> ) so the function is available to excel

Answer (score 0):

```
Select column A from first to last record and right click on that,
then change the format by clicking Format cells...
and choose whatever format you want...
```

like

[image]

then use **SUBSTITUTE(A1, "10", "Pig")** method

Comment: If the data is already on those cells, reformatting to `TEXT` will not help.

Comment: Yes, the data is already there. And I just did this format, boom, it becomes "TEXT" value of the expression result. E.g:
17:18:19
will becomes
0.721053241 (in text)

Comment: @HarryNinh then change your column format from number to text as explained here please follow this link http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/671-excel-change-number-to-text.html

Comment: @Naveen Yea I did try that one before posting here. It works for number only, not for expression (17:18) :(